# How to get the absolute path of a file in SFTP server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sftp

I have written a code that transfers file from my local machine to SFTP server using the npm package ssh2-sftp-client. I am also checking the md5 hash of the file before sending the file and after sending the file to ensure that the correct file is being transferred. To get the md5 hash of the file I'm using the npm package checksum. Before sending the file I am getting the proper hash of the file but after sending the file I am unable to get the hash of the file as I don't have it's absolute path. This is my code:

```
let Client = require("ssh2-sftp-client");
let client = new Client();
const fs = require("fs");
const checksum = require("checksum");

const sftpTransfer = () => {
  let localPath = "path-to-local-file/filename.ext";
  let data = fs.createReadStream(localPath);
  let remote = "relative-path-in-sftp-server/filename.ext";

  const config = {
    host: "IP of sftp server",
    port: "22",
    username: "username",
    password: "password",
    privateKey: fs.readFileSync("path-of-key-in-local-macchine/keyname.ppk"),
  };
  checksum.file("path-to-local-file/filename.ext", function (err, sum) {
    console.log(sum); //sum has the md5 hash of file
  });

  client
    .connect(config)
    .then(() => {
      return client.put(data, remote);
    }).then(() => {
       checksum.file("relative-path-in-sftp-server/filename.ext", function (err, sum) {
           console.log(sum); //sum has the md5 hash of file
       });
      console.log("Data Successfully Transferred!!");
      return client.end();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return err.message;
    });
};


sftpTransfer();
```

Using the `relative-path-in-sftp-server/filename.ext` I am able to transfer data and I have verified that from filezilla but I want the absolute path of the file in order to calculate it's md5 hash.

Comment: You would need to md5 the remote file though. So either use a server/client that supports  the `md5-hash` sftp extension or retrieve the file again to check it.

Comment: or ssh and run `md5sum`